# Need help in using z3 API in a c++ program

Tags: compilation, g++, z3, theorem-proving

I want to use z3 API in my C++ program. I am wondering which header files to include and how to run a program which contains z3 functions etc.

I saw the `example.cpp` file which comes with z3 source code and in order to run this file, I had to run `make examples` in the build directory which internally executed the command

```
g++ -o cpp_example  -I../src/api -I../src/api/c++ 
    ../examples/c++/example.cpp libz3.so -lpthread -fopenmp -lrt
```

Now if I create any program, do I need to compile it like this (include `../src/api` and link with lib files) every time I need to compile my program?

Please help me, I have never used z3 before. Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes, you'll need the same compiler flags everytime. Often, people encapsulate these build rules in Makefiles.

Comment: @crowder: ohh :( Do I need to have all of the subdirectories and files z3 directory in order to use z3 commands OR can I keep some of them which are necessary to compile a file(and which ones are necessary)?

Comment: My guess is that you'll find those includes have inter-dependencies that you'll have trouble discerning or disentangling. I don't know what z3's license is like (you should understand this issue before distributing source code), but you will probably need the whole thing or most of it, to build your project, assuming you're really using it thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

The command-line in your question is used in one of the Z3 example applications. This command line is executed in the `build` directory. The build directory contains the Z3 compiled library: `libz3.so`. The command may seem complicated because it is compiling and linking the application with a single command. The directive `-I<path-name>` instructs g++ to look for include files in the given directory. Finally, the command can be executed even if we do not install the Z3 include files and library in the system.

To install the Z3 include files and library in our system, we should execute `sudo make install`. Then, assume we create a file `tst.cpp` containing

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<z3++.h>
using namespace z3;

int main() {
    context c;
    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    std::cout << x + 1 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it, we can just use:

```
g++ -c tst.cpp
```

To link and generate the executable, we can use:

```
g++ -o tst tst.o -lz3
```

Finally, we can execute it

```
./tst
```